# customized UIpaging Control

Tags: iphone, uipagecontrol

I have implemented a UIPaging control and now i want to replace the default dots by image dots. How can i do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this extension to UIPageControl

https://github.com/simonmaddox/SMPageControl

It will allow you to colour the dots, however you could easily adapt to handle images in the overriden drawRect method

Answer (score 0):

Uipagecontrol does nothing. You can use an scroll view with image views in it and use scroll view delegates.

Docs:

[UIScrollView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

[UIScrollViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html)

Comment: i have also implemented UIScrollView along with UIPageControl, i want to know how i can change the colors of dots in UIPageControl or add images instead of dots.